# What is the most elegant way to create CSS for this example?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create CSS for this example:

[image]

The issue I am encountering now is row1, col3 is not staying put when browser is resized.

I'm not too concerned about the color scheme, just the most efficient cross-browser way to create the CSS

I was thinking about using tables, but wanted to try to get this to work using CSS and DIV first.

Here's a sample of what I have so far:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drdexter33/7r15p76h/5/)

```css
html{height:100%;}

body {
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    color: #232323;
    height:100%;
    /*background-color: #fff;*/
    background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#782be0, #451883); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#782be0, #451883); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#782be0, #451883); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#782be0, #451883); /* Standard syntax */
}

header, footer, nav, section {
    display: block;
}



/* Styles for columns
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
.col-1 { 
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f30c48, #850b2b); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: linear-gradient(#f30c48, #850b2b); /* Standard syntax */
}
.col-2 {
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f30c48, #850b2b); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: linear-gradient(#3e3e3e, #030303); /* Standard syntax */

}
.col-3 {  
    
    width: 150px;
    height:20px;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f30c48, #850b2b); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: linear-gradient(#3e3e3e, #030303); /* Standard syntax */
    
}

.col-4 { 
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f30c48, #850b2b); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: linear-gradient(#3e3e3e, #030303); /* Standard syntax */
}

.col-5 { 
   width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f30c48, #850b2b); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: linear-gradient(#3e3e3e, #030303); /* Standard syntax */
}


[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 25px;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top:25px;
    
    
}


/* Styles for basic forms
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
div { 
    text-align:center; 
}




label{ 
    color:white;
    font-size:225px;
    height:100px;
    line-height:180px;
}


.labelOne{
    color:white;
    font-size:16px;
    height:12px;
    line-height:16px;
}

.labelTwo {
  color:white;
    font-size:16px;
    height:16px;
    line-height:16px;
    
    text-align:left;
    
}

.labelThree{
     color:white;
    font-size:16px;
    height:12px;
    line-height:16px;
}

.labelFour{
   
    color:white;
     font-size:16px;
    height:12px;
    line-height:16px;

}

.smallLabel{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    color:white;
    float:right;
    font-size:60px;
    height:12px;
    line-height:12px;
}

.smallLabelTwo{
    display:inline-block;
    color:white;
 font-size:36px;
    height:36px;
    line-height:36px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <label class="labelOne">CALLS WAITING</label>
        <p><label id="callsWaiting"></label></p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-2">
        <label class="labelOne">AVAILABLE</label>
        <p><label id="available"> </label>  </p>
    </div>

   
        <div class="col-3">
            <label class="labelTwo">LUNCH BREAKS</label>
            <label class="smallLabel" id="breaksLunch">0</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
            <label class="labelTwo">MEETING TRAINING</label>
            <label class="smallLabel" id="meetingTraining">0</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
            <label class="labelTwo">NOT AVAILABLE</label>
            <label class="smallLabel" id="notAvailable">0</label>
        </div>
    
</div>

<div style="clear:both;">
    
    <div class="col-4">
        <label class="labelThree">INBOUND</label>
        <p><label class="smallLabelTwo" id="inBound"></label></p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-5">
        <label class="labelFour">OUTBOUND</label>
        <p><label class="smallLabelTwo" id="outBound"></label></p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: However, it looks like tabular data to me..I'd have no problem with using a table here.

Comment: `label` is meant to label form fields like an input, select or textarea (with a for attribute on label and id on the form field with same value on both) thus providing an explanation to the user on what he should type or check or select (Name, Country, Yes/No, etc). Here it can't; a simple paragraph could be used for each colored square (or a paragraph into a div, it's more 'layout-proof')